Git LFS pointer files not converting to binary files after checkout in a Jenkins Pipeline
I'm using Git LFS to manage binary files.
Jenkins pipeline script performs a Git checkout and then runs git lfs pull orgin as follows:
checkout scmGit(branches: [[name: 'DEVELOPMENT']], extensions: [lfs()], gitTool: 'GIT_Unix', userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: 'JK_USR', url: 'https://localgit/myorg/SOMETHING.git']])

However, after the checkout, I've noticed that the LFS pointer files remain as pointers and are not being replaced by the actual binary files. What could be causing this issue?
Here are the relevant Jenkins logs:
 > /2.17.1/bin/git config --add remote.origin.fetch +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
 > /2.17.1/bin/git rev-parse origin/DEVELOPMENT^{commit} # timeout=10
 > /2.17.1/bin/git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > /2.17.1/bin/git checkout -f 88dcff7dbe2992bf94253fb1d943e7840f78cfd5 # timeout=20
 > /2.17.1/bin/git config --get remote.origin.url # timeout=10
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials Service Id 
 > /2.17.1/bin/git lfs pull origin # timeout=20
Commit message: "Merge branch 'DEVELOPMENT' of https://localgit/myorg/SOMETHING into DEVELOPMENT"
 > /2.17.1/bin/git rev-list --no-walk 88dcff7dbe2992bf94253fb1d943e7840f78cfd5 # timeout=10

